# Limit programs based off group policy

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2012, group-policy

What I'm attempting to accomplish is having certain executables allowed in a 2012 Active Directory environment based off of a group policy.

I have 3 different types of users in my AD.

Group A should only have access to foo.exe.
Group B should have access to bar.exe. 
And finally Group C should have access to foo.exe and bar.exe.

How do I accomplish this using my 2012 server? 
I have seen different sites using the physical machine with gpedit.msc but I would like this implemented on a server level because I have roaming profiles set up and it would be easily scale-able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> having certain executables allowed in a 2012 Active Directory
>   environment based off of a group policy.
>
> Group A should only have access to foo.exe. Group B should have access
>   to bar.exe. And finally Group C should have access to foo.exe and
>   bar.exe. How do I accomplish this using my 2012 server?

So assuming these are `.NET` or some type of executable files that can be run on the client side without actually being installed locally or a terminal server, etc. you could put each app executable file in its own network share folder location.

Each app folder would have ***its own separate AD security group*** with whatever access is needed to run it (e.g. read and execute, etc.). This way you could put each individual AD user account in the app security group for each to ensure they have access to one, the other, or both. You could also nest the groups and if you have an AD security groups that contains Group A, Group B, and Group C, you could make each of them a member of the correlated app security groups they need access to.

Finally, you setup [**Group Policy Preferences**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn581922.aspx), to then create a shortcut to these locations as icons on the desktop or other locations for only those user accounts that are in a specific AD security group.

See the below detail (and screen shots) for the navigation and options you'd select when setting something up for this need. You'd obviously need to plug in your environment details for the group names and UNC paths, and so on.

Simply test to confirm all works as expected with your AD account (give enough time to propagate throughout your domain) or a dummy/test AD account once you get the GPP, security groups, folder locations and security, etc. setup accordingly.

---

### EXAMPLE FOLDER STRUCTURE

- `\\servername\sharename\apps\Foo\Foo.exe`

  - Group A and Group C - Read access
- `\\servername\sharename\apps\Bar\Bar.exe`

  - Group B and Group C - Read access

---

### GROUP POLICY INFORMATION

**Navigation:** *User Configuration | Preferences | Windows Settings | Shortcuts*

- *Right-Click Shortcut | New | Shortcut*

**General Tab**

[image: Foo App1]

**Common Tab**

[image: Foo App2]

**Targeting Option from Common Tab**

[image: Foo App3]

Answer (score 1):

Please note that when using the share approach outlined by 1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish, users could still access the applications if they know the share names (and they might easily be able to browse for them)

To secure the above method either hide the shares (append a "$" sign to the end of the share name) or (or rather **and**) change the security properties of the shares to only allow access from the individual groups discussed.

You might also want to have a look at the "applocker" feature:

[How to configure AppLocker Group Policy to prevent software from running](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5211.how-to-configure-applocker-group-policy-to-prevent-software-from-running.aspx)

[Managing AppLocker in Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8/8.1](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/Windows_Server_2012_Security/managing-applocker-windows-server-2012-and-windows-8-81-part3.html)

Comment: Just a note: The OP tagged this as Windows 7; so AppLocker is not available in Windows 7 Professional; (although it is available in Enterprise)